# res.send not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am working with a simple CRUD app with jquery ajax and node.js, just to improve my skills with node and ajax. The thing is that I am doing a post request that is handled with my post router in the node server, and everything is working fine. It adds 1 more product to my products.json file, but in the end it doesn't send the response back to the client, the final res.send("done") doesn't work and I don't know why..

**here is the code:**

**ajax**

```
$("#create-form").on('submit',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var createIn = $("#create-input").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/products',
        method:'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({name:createIn}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $("create-input").val("");
          $("get-button").click(); 
        }
    });
})
```

**node**

```
app.post('/products',function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('products.json','utf8',function(err,data){
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var productName = req.body.name;
        console.log(req.body.name);
        currentId++;
        var productId = currentId;
        var product = {
            name: productName,
            id: productId
        }
        result.products.push(product);
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/products.json",JSON.stringify(result),'utf8');
     });
    res.send("post done");
});
```

This is just the important part of the code, it works and just fails at the end in the res.send.

Comment: What node library are you using for routing?

Comment: i am doing it directly, no routes, because i dont need it for this small aplication

Comment: What is your variable `app` an instance of?

Comment: var app = express();

Comment: Try adding an error function on the client code, to see whether you get a response

Comment: Have you ever tried to add an **error** prop and its handler fn to your Ajax options, sth like that • $. ajax({ ... error: function(xhr, error){console.debug(xhr);console.debug(error);} •

Comment: i have a parse error and received a object in the error function that says the responsemessage is ok, how can i see better the error?

Comment: Ok, that helped me spot the error - see new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client code is looking for a json response, but you are returning a string.

```
$("#create-form").on('submit',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var createIn = $("#create-input").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/products',
        method:'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({name:createIn}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",           <--------------
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $("create-input").val("");
          $("get-button").click(); 
        }
    });
})
```

Either delete this line or add on the server side

```
res.send({"message":"post done"});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, now i get the res.send answer, but should it not continue on the success ajax and  do the 3 lines on the sucess?

Comment: worketd, was focused on other things and forget the main, i forget the id on the 2 lines ofc it does not work, but before the problem was with the dataType, thank you very much great eye :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly but you should ideally not send back the response until you know the work has been done, and you should handle errors. In other words you should use the callbacks.  (Too many callbacks can be problematic and you should investigate other patterns - eg promises - bit no need here)

```
app.post('/products',function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('products.json','utf8',function(err,data){
        if (err) return res.send("error");
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var productName = req.body.name;
        console.log(req.body.name);
        currentId++;
        var productId = currentId;
        var product = {
            name: productName,
            id: productId
        }
        result.products.push(product);
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/products.json",JSON.stringify(result),'utf8', function(err, res) {
         if (err) return res.send("error");
         res.send("post done");
        });
     });

});
```

Comment: This is clearly a better way to write the routeHandler but I feel like if his problem is that the `res.send` is not sending a response back to the client that this will not solve his problem.

Comment: you can also do `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.writeFileSync` to make it synchronous

Comment: right i know how to handle the errors, the thing is that i dont get any error, my server just does not respond back.

Comment: @NikhilMotiani I strongly recommend against using the `Sync` variants of `readFile` and `writeFile` in a server. Node is single threaded so the sync calls are blocking, which means that while they are executing no other operations can be done. In other words, your server will freeze up until your sync calls finish.

Comment: fs.readFileSync and writeFileSync does not solve my problem, i need to know what is happening, it add the product to my product.json, but it does not send back to my ajax request

Comment: @wex, agreed its not a good way to do a synchronous read and write. But can't it be used while debugging?

Comment: i understand that and i agree, i am not a expert with node.js but doing the readFile and writeFile process syncronous does not solve it :/